# Seesaw-V2 Vs Apache HTTP Vs NGINX

Tags: apache, nginx, load-balancing, seesaw

What are the similarities and differences among

1. Seesaw-V2 (Google Open Sourced)
2. Apache HTTP
3. NGINX

in terms of Load Balancing only.